# SystemVerilog Parallel Constraint

Tags: system-verilog

In the below code, bit 'a' is distributed equally between 1 and 0. Also, it is constrained to 1 using parallel constraint. My initial guess, we would get five 1 and five fail randomization. Instead of that, we got 10 1's. Can anyone explain reason behind it?

```
program test1;

    class test;

        rand bit a;

        constraint con1 {a dist {0:=5,1:=5};}

        constraint con2 {a == 1'b1;}

        function display();
            $display(a);
        endfunction

    endclass

    test t;

    initial begin

        t = new();
        repeat(10)
            begin
                assert(t.randomize);
                t.display();
            end

    end

endprogram
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1800-2012 LRM section 18.5.4

> Absent any other constraints, the probability that the expression
>   matches any value in the list is proportional to its specified weight.
>   If there are constraints on some expressions that cause the
>   distribution weights on these expressions to be not satisfiable,
>   implementations are only required to satisfy the constraints. An
>   exception to this rule is a weight of zero, which is treated as a
>   constraint.

So it is the same as if you had written

```
constraint con1 {a dist {1:=5};}
```

Comment: I didnt understand the last line "An exception to this rule is a weight of zero, which is treated as a constraint." Can you please kidnly explain a little bit more. Why is 0:=5 not taken here?

Comment: 0:=5, the weight is 5, not 0. Let's say you had `rand int i;` and the constraint `i dist {1:=5,2:=5,3:=0};` The weight of 0 is treated the same as if you had the constraint `i != 3`